# Removing the white space between UITableView and UIRefreshControl when dragging

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a table view with UIRefreshControl.

The first row of the table is Blue and the UIRefreshControl background color is blue too.

when I drag the table down in order to refresh it I got a this white line separating the table and UIRefreshControl.

This line is disappearing when i stop dragging the table.

How can I remove this white line without changing the tableview background color which is white?

Image attached for clarification: [image: Snapshot]

Comment: Here is an example project https://encodable.com/uploaddemo/files/tableWithReferesh.zip

Comment: I have this same issue...

Comment: How did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Jing's answer, I made a gap-cover view and introduced it behind the refresh control. I didn't need to do any scroll-time adjustments since the negative y-position was sufficient.

```
let gapCoverView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -200, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 250))
gapCoverView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
self.view.insertSubview(gapCoverView, belowSubview: refreshControl!)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a work around to solve this issue. If you don't want to change the background color of the table view and still want to remove this space.

Basically create a `UIView *view` behind the `UIRefreshControl`, and set the background color of the view to the color you want in `viewDidLoad` method

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //you implementation of viewDidLoad
    self.view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,0)];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yourBackgroundColor];
    [self.tableView insertSubview:self.view belowSubview:self.refreshControl];
}
```

Then implement a `UIScrollViewDelegate` method to dynamically change the height of the view behind the `UIRefreshControl` to cover up the gap.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, offset + 20)]; // or any small number
}
```

Note you might still see a line because it's the separator of the tableview, you can change the `tableView`'s separator color or style to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently too, it seems to me like it could be a bug in `UIRefreshControl`. I posted what I think is happening [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331691/white-line-below-uirefreshcontrol-when-pulled-tableview/50670500#50670500).