# Removing white space between Tableview and Refresh Control iOS 14

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios14, uirefreshcontrol

I have a tableview with a refresh control that has a custom background colour but when I actually pull to refresh I can see there is light grey line that appears between the 2 when the tableview is bouncing vertically.

[image]

This is not an issue in any iOS version before 14.

What I've tried but doesn't work:

```
var frame = tableView.bounds
frame.origin.y = -frame.size.height
refreshBackgroundView.frame = frame
refreshBackgroundView.backgroundColor = .blue
tableView.addSubview(refreshBackgroundView)
        
let refresh = UIRefreshControl()
refresh.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pulledToRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
refresh.tintColor = .white
refresh.backgroundColor = .blue

tableView.refreshControl = refresh
tableView.addSubview(refresh)
```

Any ideas what else I could try?

Comment: For anybody that gets stuck with this please find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50670500/3711270

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the frames aren't being updated as fast as you scroll. Try this:

```
final class RefreshControl: UIRefreshControl {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let originalFrame = frame
        frame = originalFrame
    }
}
```